# jquery selection attribute present and child of element

Tags: jquery

The task I have is to test if one or more children of an element has a given property if the markup is

```
<div>
   <div attributename="xyz" />
</div>
```

then the test is true however if the markup is

```
<div>
   <div>
      <div attributename="xyz" />
   </div>
</div>
```

then the result should be false.

so far I've gotten to

```
$(":[attributename]",context);
```

but that will return true for both scenarios

Comment: you have mentioned both results should be true which is the correct one?

Comment: as per your question you want result to be true in both cases, that's what you are getting. Then what's the question asked for?

Comment: @Murtaza: The question states that children should be tested. Given that `context` is the outermost `div`, only the first HTML structure should give a result.

Comment: @RuneFS: You should remove the `:` from the selector as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this...

```
$(context).children(":[attributename]");
```

---

When you do this...

```
$(":[attributename]",context)
```

...its just a roundabout way of doing this...

```
$(context).find(":[attributename]")
```

...which shows much more clearly what is happening. You're searching all descendants.

Comment: the first part will do the trick. The latter however is incorrect. In _most_ cases it's correct but when, as in mine, context can be null they are not equivalent. E.g $(null).find("div") will return an empty array when executed against this page where $("div",null) will return an array with several div elements

Comment: @RuneFS: Irrespective of whether or not `null` works, the second half of the answer is correct. This is because passing `null` as the `context` argument is not supported by the API. The only supported values are *"A DOM Element, Document, or jQuery to use as context"*. And the docs state: *"Internally, selector context is implemented with the `.find()` method, so `$('span', this)` is equivalent to `$(this).find('span')`."* So while `null` may work, you shouldn't rely on it. Instead you should be explicit with `$('selector', context || document)`.

Comment: $(selector,context) is implemented using find in the case where context is different from null and $(selector).find(otherSelector) is equivalent to ($selector,null).find(otherselector) since not passing an argument to a method call is equivalent to passing null for that argument.

Comment: @RuneFS: Not passing an argument is not equivalent to passing `null`. One might assume that it is equivalent to passing `undefined` *(which is a separate value)*, but that isn't strictly correct either. If I do `$(selector, undefined)`, the `arguments.length` is `2`. If I do `$(selector)`, the `arguments.length` is `1`. This is an important distinction. There was a Mozilla bug a while back *(I don't remember exactly where)* because they deviated from the spec and relied on the `undefined` value of the second argument, assuming it meant nothing was passed. It has since been fixed.

Comment: ...If your argument is that it's equivalent in *behavior*, then you're missing my point. You shouldn't rely on a behavior when it's a result of a deviation from the documented API. There are only 3 valid arguments for the `context`, and I stated them above.

Answer (score 0):

Are you referring to `>` selector which only selects elements which are a direct descendant?

```
$("> div[attributename=xyz]",context);
```

**Please read comments below this answer!**

Comment: The [docs](http://api.jquery.com/child-selector/) warn that using the `>` selector without a left hand operand shouldn't be used because it will be deprecated in the future.